# Why does ToString() on generic types have square brackets?

Tags: c#, generics

Why does `new List<string>().ToString();` return the following:?

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Why wouldn't it just bring back `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>`. 
What's with the strange non C# syntax?

Comment: Just in case yo would like to get name with <> brackets http://stackoverflow.com/a/14284719/797249

Comment: To the person who voted to close this because it's opinion based. How is it opinion based? The answer provided is completely objective.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `<>` brackets is C# syntax. The `System.Object.ToString()` implementation returns the type name with the CLR syntax.

Consider this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>
```

Looks nice when you're developing in C#, but say you call `ToString` from C++/CLI. Would you expect the following instead?

```
System::Collections::Generic::List<System::String>
```

Obviously, the behavior shouldn't change based on which language the caller was compiled in, so the returned string is language-neutral.

---

[This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) lists the type name conventions used by the CLR. (Thanks to [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) for the link).

As for the arity (the `` `1 `` part), you can find more info in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (the CLI specification):

> **I.10.7.2 Type names and arity encoding**
>
> CLS-compliant generic type names are encoded using the format `` name[`arity] `` , where `[...]` indicates that the grave accent character `` ` `` and *arity* together are optional. The encoded name shall follow these rules:
>
> 1. *name* shall be an ID (see Partition II) that does not contain the `` ` `` character.
> 2. *arity* is specified as an unsigned decimal number without leading zeros or spaces.
> 3. For a normal generic type, *arity* is the number of type parameters declared on the type.
> 4. For a nested generic type, *arity* is the number of newly introduced type parameters.

Comment: Also see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a table with all the different symbols used for CLR type names.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks for the link, I was actually trying to find that in the docs, I'll add that to the answer if you don't mind

Comment: Wish I could upvote once more for adding the CLI specification.. :)

Comment: @GiladGreen :-)