# Get Type Name BUT resolve it with specified usings

Tags: c#, reflection

There are like 1000 posts telling me how to get a TypeName, like

[Get type name without full namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396300/get-type-name-without-full-namespace-in-c-sharp)

[Get the type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579734/get-the-type-name)

and many many more, and all are working fine, BUT I need to get the TypeName resolved with usings provided.

For example I have the following using:

```
using Foo = System.Collections.Generic;
```

and now the following call to get the name:

```
var x = typeof (Foo.List<>);
var y = x.Name;
```

I would like to get the output

```
Foo.List`1
```

instead of only

```
List`1
```

Is this possible, or is the only choice string manipulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` directives are a purely compile-time construct.

That is fundamentally impossible; the information you want does not exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is syntactic sugar for the C# language it's not a fundamental feature of .NET in and of itself.