# How to get string representation of a built-in type alias

Tags: c#

If I use `typeof(int).Name`, I get "Int32".
Is there a way to get "int" directly from the system, without me doing any string operations on the "Int32"?

Comment: Can you add a dictionary that maps from `Type` to `string` and look up with it?

Comment: I was hoping to get it from an already existing dictionary listing some available types. :)

Comment: See the discussion in [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579755/5133585). Getting a "C# native way" of writing the type name isn't particularly useful. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: `int` is a C#-ism, there is nothing in the runtime that knows about his language-specific name (as well there shouldn't be, popular as it is, C# isn't the only .NET language). You can write a simple lookup table for all the types C# has dedicated names for; it's a fixed list. Conceivably you could also rely on Roslyn (somehow) but that seems massive overkill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get a type's alias through reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection) The exact duplicate

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ah yes, this is actually exactly the same case, didn't see it in the recommendations though. I will mark it as a duplicate. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a dictionary for this. Most probably got it from another StackOverflow answer a few years ago, but can't find it at the moment...

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> Aliases =
    new Dictionary<Type, string>()
{
    { typeof(byte), "byte" },
    { typeof(sbyte), "sbyte" },
    { typeof(short), "short" },
    { typeof(ushort), "ushort" },
    { typeof(int), "int" },
    { typeof(uint), "uint" },
    { typeof(long), "long" },
    { typeof(ulong), "ulong" },
    { typeof(float), "float" },
    { typeof(double), "double" },
    { typeof(decimal), "decimal" },
    { typeof(object), "object" },
    { typeof(bool), "bool" },
    { typeof(char), "char" },
    { typeof(string), "string" },
    { typeof(void), "void" }
};
```

Comment: `string result = Aliases.TryGetValue(typeOfInterest, out string value) ? value : typeOfInterest.Name;`

Comment: I guess it was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362899/4728685), looks like an exact duplicate